# What methods exist for handling DB Change Management?

Tags: database, version-control

I recently began working with version control in my web-development using subversion.  This works great for managing the files I develop but does nothing for the changes I sometimes need to make to the databases.  To my knowledge the server I'm working on doesn't have any DB management systems in place and I likely wouldn't be able to get them to install anything.  What options are there for managing DB's in this kind of environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156110/version-control-of-databases

Comment: @Jeff O This thread you suggested deals more with versioned content rather than the versioning of the database structure which is what I would like to be able to track.  Thanks though for the suggestion!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

K. Scott Allen has written some excellent blog posts about this a few years ago. They might be "old" in internet terms, but his solution is still very nice.

1. [Three rules for database work](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/01/30/11702.aspx)
2. [The Baseline](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/01/31/11710.aspx)
3. [Change Scripts](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/11721.aspx)
4. [Views, Stored Procedures and the Like](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/11737.aspx)
5. [Branching and Merging](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/03/11746.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Migration frameworks are code libraries that provide a simple API to automate DB changes, with some mechanism for versioning the DB.

I use [Migrator.Net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/wiki/GettingStarted) for some projects.  I create a class for each changeset, and the framework provides a simple way to execute the changes against a DB.  I can also run changes forwards and backwards, provided I code the logic for downgrading as well as upgrading.

We then manage the migration code in our VCS like any other code.

Answer (score 1):

Nightly backups of course (at least) .. Because its not just the DB structure you care about.

You have several options:

1) Keep your alter scripts in the Source control.

2) After each db change generate the Db scripts.. and Store those in Source control along with a DB backup at the same time.  This way you can do a compare on the Generated Script file.